# Ansible to_nice_json with line breaks

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to spit out a bit of YAML config as json using `to_json` filter to make it more human readable. I noticed that this filter will put all json on one line.

Then I tried `to_nice_json`. The output looks very much the same. There are no line breaks so the json becomes a nicely formatted one liner.

Is it possible to format to nice json with line breaks?

Comment: Same problem :/

Answer (score 2):

In the end I achieved the results I wanted with

```
to_nice_json(ensure_ascii=False,indent=2)
```